# Query recently uninstalled rpm packages

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

There's a option in rpm to query recently installed packages using
**rpm -q  --last**

But, is there a option to query recently uninstalled package ?

Comment: I don't think so... rpm keeps track of everything that is installed and under control of an rpm; but I don't think it keeps track of all uninstalled packages... that is quite unmanageable I guess

Comment: Yea, I've gone through the man pages. But, tough luck !!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so... rpm keeps track of everything that is installed and under control of an rpm; but I doesn't keeps track of all uninstalled packages (afaik) ... that is quite unmanageable I guess.

The closest you could get is go through your command history and find all commands executed to remove rpm's:

```
history | grep "rpm -e"
```

or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, it does help to an extent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd have liked to help more :)

Answer (score 1):

rpm itself is not capable of doing this but usually you do not use such low-level too for removing packages. These higher-level tools e.g. yum in Fedora tracks these changes to */var/log/yum.log*; similar tools are available in most of the current linux distribution (apt in Ubutnu/Debian; yast2 in SuSe). Of course, if you will use rpm directly then it will not be in log files.